# What can I do when ERROR in 'pip install docx'?

Tags: python, pip, docx

I get an error from install docx.

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/7c/rs7hcc6s2s5dpgx4mdv2rfbw0000gn/T/pip-install-mg_b3pvz/lxml_10985d3936374ca8bf2b4a3b56b75126/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/7c/rs7hcc6s2s5dpgx4mdv2rfbw0000gn/T/pip-install-mg_b3pvz/lxml_10985d3936374ca8bf2b4a3b56b75126/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/7c/rs7hcc6s2s5dpgx4mdv2rfbw0000gn/T/pip-record-ymlexg8f/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers /Users/jinshengxu/Library/Python/3.9/include/python3.9/lxml Check the logs for full command output.`

I try to install this package.

Comment: Please share your command used and the Platform (looks like macos though)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the details when you choose a package.  `docx` is an antique that hasn't been updated in **9 years**.  You should install `python-docx` instead.